# meaning of Press Book

Tags: meaning, expressions

I can't understand the meaning of "press book" in the sentence below:

> They could marry soon. Preparations for a wedding had been in the Royal family’s *press book* since she was sixteen; they could pull it out in a month if they wanted to.

Who is talking is a princess of a fairy tale, but she lives in a imaginary kingdom that seems United Kingdom.

Comment: From the context I can guess what it must mean, but I am not familiar with the phrase, and without such context I would know know what it meant (Engish, native speaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *press book*, in this context, may be used to emphasise the fact that the wedding of the 16-year-old lady had been planned for years, so it's something prearranged and well-known to everybody. If something is *written in the press book* of a person, it is going to happen in the future regardless of the  individual's will; the meaning is close to that of *[to be written in the stars](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/written-in-the-stars)*, but with the difference that at the origin of the prearrangement there is a person/a community and not an abstract entity as that of Destiny.

I'm brought to this conclusion by [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressbook), where it's said that a press book...

> ... is a collection of works and communications used to represent an individual, group of individuals, service, company or product. It is usually associated with creative professionals. It may be textual,graphic (photo, illustration,painting...), animated (video/film,3D...), or algorithmic (games...).
>   
>   **It may include** press releases, advertisings, editorials, instructions for use, or **any information that pertains to that person**/product, or of works and communications used to represent an individual, group of individuals, service, company, or product. It is usually associated with creative professionals.